# Do I need check destination string length using strcat inside a for loop

Tags: c, string

```
char command [][12] = {
                   {"Attention!!"},
                   {"About Turn!"},
                   {"Left Turn!"},
                   {"right Turn!"},
                   {"Dismiss!"}
                  };

int i;
for (i=1; i<5; i++)   
 {
    strcat (command [0], command [i]); 
 }
printf ("length of command[0]:%ld\nNew string:%s\n", strlen(command[0]), command[0]);
```

In the above block of code, do I need to check destination string `command[0]` to see if it has enough space for the other 4 strings?

I didn't do that but it turns out the compiler didn' t report any error and printed out the concatenated string.

Is it ok to do it like this with a for loop?

Comment: Yes you have to. Check the output of the `command[1]`, `command[2]`, etc. after your loop, you would be surprised I think.

Comment: Nope, it's not ok. Try printing `command[1]` after the loop and you'll see why.

Comment: the main problem with the code is that command[0] has no room to strcat anything.   you need to char* dest = malloc( strlen(command[0])+strlen(command[1])+1 ),  then strcpy( dest, command[0]), then strcat( dest, command[1])   I you plan on separating the two strings via a space, then the malloc needs to be (at least) one char larger and there needs to be a strcat(dest, " "); after the (above) call to strcpy()

Comment: regarding this question: "In the above block of code, do I need to check destination string command[0] to see if it has enough space for the other 4 strings?"  There will be zero (0) room to strcat anything to the command[0].

Comment: Re the title question: unless you have allocated enough memory specifically for the strings you want to concatenate (and a termintor) then **yes**. Even then, it's good practice to check the available space first, or perhaps use a safer function like `strcat_s()`

Comment: @WeatherVane: ... or, instead of `strcat_s()`, the standard `strncat()`.

Comment: @TimČas  `strncat()` also has the more secure version `strncat_s()`

Comment: @WeatherVane: ... the latter is not part of the base C standard, **and non-portable**. A personal aside: in my opinion, the `_s` family of functions are just silly attempts at API lock-in by Microsoft. Especially since we're talking about C, where safety isn't exactly number 1 concern.

Comment: @TimČas my first point was still good. But if you want to opinionate that MS is *silly* this isn't the forum to do so. I voted up your first response!

Comment: The code above works and concatenates the strings because there is actually space after command[0]. What is happening is that strcat is "eating" the space used by command [1], command[2], etc, which in most compilers will just follow the memory reserved for command[0]. Noe thosugh that this code is not portable is not guaranteed to work and might cause memory problems depending on the compiler. A good excersice here is debugging, so you can see your variable addresses in memory. This will give you a good idea of what is happening.

Comment: Hi guys, I know it's a good practice to do that I just couldn't figure out why the result seems fine. I was running it on Ubuntu. using gcc compiler. now it makes sense. thanks for everyone's reply and thanks for whoever corrected my spelling.

Comment: Your code needs to ensure the destination string is long enough to hold the result (including the trailing `'\0'`).    Copying more characters to an array than the array can hold gives undefined behaviour.    Undefined behaviour means "no limit on permitted behaviours" which, unfortunately, permits code to APPEAR to function correctly even if a destination array is not long enough to hold what is being copied to it.   If you are not sure if the array is long enough, then you need to check before copying.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do need to consider the space available in the target string
when using `strcat()`.  In fact, you need to consider the available
space for all string manipulation operations.  If you don't know that
there is enough space, you are not safe.

Consider the array:

```
char command[][12] =
{
    {"Attention!!"},
    {"About Turn!"},
    {"Left Turn!"},
    {"Right Turn!"},
    {"Dismiss!"}
};
```

The memory for the array looks like this, using `$` to represent `'\0'`

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| A | t | t | e | n | t | i | o | n | ! | ! | $ |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| A | b | o | u | t |   | T | u | r | n | ! | $ |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| L | e | f | t |   | T | u | r | n | ! | $ | $ |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| R | i | g | h | t |   | T | u | r | n | ! | $ |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| D | i | s | m | i | s | s | ! | $ | $ | $ | $ |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

The specification of `strcat()` says:

> The `strcat` function appends a copy of the string pointed to by `s2`
>   (including the terminating null character) to the end of the string
>   pointed to by `s1`.  The initial character of `s2` overwrites the null
>   character at the end of `s1`.  If copying takes place between objects
>   that overlap, the behavior is undefined.

Your processing loop is:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{
    strcat(command[0], command[i]);
}
```

It is fairly clear that you are invoking undefined behaviour because the
extended material in `command[0]` runs over the content of `command[1]`.
Nevertheless, some common implementations will actually behave sensibly,
but there is no guarantee that every implementation will.

Indeed, when run on macOS Sierra 10.12.2 with GCC 6.3.0, the first
iteration of the loop generates an `Abort trap: 6` error.  This is a
perfectly legitimate result of 'undefined behaviour'.

However, if we 'reimplement' `strcat()` to behave as you might expect, 
what you end up with is:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| A | t | t | e | n | t | i | o | n | ! | ! | A |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| b | o | u | t |   | T | u | r | n | ! | L | e |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| f | t |   | T | u | r | n | ! | R | i | g | h |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| t |   | T | u | r | n | ! | D | i | s | m | i |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| s | s | ! | $ | i | s | s | ! | $ | $ | $ | $ |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

#### Demonstration code

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static inline void n_strcat(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    memmove(s1 + strlen(s1), s2, strlen(s2) + 1);
}

#ifndef USE_REAL_STRCAT
#undef strcat
#define strcat(s1, s2)  n_strcat(s1, s2)
#endif /* USE_REAL_STRCAT */

static void print_bar(int cols)
{
    printf("    +");
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
        printf("---+");
    putchar('\n');
}

static void print_cmd(int rows, int cols, char cmd[rows][cols])
{
    print_bar(cols);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        printf("    |");
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            unsigned char u = cmd[i][j];
            if (!isprint(u))
                u = '$';
            printf(" %c |", u);
        }
        putchar('\n');
        print_bar(cols);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char command[][12] =
    {
        { "Attention!!" },
        { "About Turn!" },
        { "Left Turn!"  },
        { "Right Turn!" },
        { "Dismiss!"    },
    };
    enum { CMD_ROWS = sizeof(command) / sizeof(command[0]) };
    enum { CMD_COLS = sizeof(command[0]) / sizeof(command[0][0]) };

    print_cmd(CMD_ROWS, CMD_COLS, command);

    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        strcat(command[0], command[i]);
    printf("\nLength of command[0]: %zu\nNew string: [%s]\n\n", strlen(command[0]), command[0]);

    print_cmd(CMD_ROWS, CMD_COLS, command);
    return 0;
}
```

The output from the program is the two tables shown above, with this information in between:

```
Length of command[0]: 51
New string: [Attention!!About Turn!Left Turn!Right Turn!Dismiss!]
```